# print ARG value in docker build

Tags: docker, docker-build

Is there a way to print `ARG`s values, that are passed via the `--build-arg` flags to a `docker build` command?

Just using `RUN echo $ARG_NAME` isn't enough since I want it to be printed before the `FROM` section, where it's not allowed.

The point is to see these values immediately so I can stop the build quickly, preventing downloading the wrong base images.

Already searched docker docs and google. Maybe someone here can shed some light.

Answer (score 11):

You could use a multi-stage build where the first stage is just for diagnostics and otherwise gets completely ignored.

```sh
FROM busybox
ARG ARG_NAME
RUN echo $ARG_NAME

FROM python:3.8
ARG ARG_NAME
...
CMD ["my_app"]
```

Note that Docker layer caching can cause `RUN` steps to be totally skipped so even this isn't 100% reliable.

Comment: Good idea! The skipping problem may be solved with the flag `docker build --no-cache .`

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible

> A Dockerfile must begin with a `FROM` instruction

see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

The execution of the `RUN` command will be performed in an intermediate container that has to be created of an image.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :). I'm aware of that. That's why I mentioned I can't use `RUN echo....`. I was wondering whether there's some other way / workaround, maybe some verbosity level...

Comment: Sorry but a Dockerfile may not start with FROM instruction since it is possible to pass the base image as a build variable. In this case, Dockerfile will start with ARG VARNAME, then FROM VARNAME. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact